# Textfield MAterial UI width fit to content

Tags: dynamic, material-ui, width, textfield

I want to dynamically the TextField component in Material UI ver 5, changes to fit the content size. I used chatGPT and the solution does not work :
Chat GPT Solution :

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

function DynamicWidthTextField() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <TextField
      label="Dynamic Width TextField"
      variant="outlined"
      fullWidth   // Ensures TextField takes full width of its container
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      InputProps={{
        style: {
          width: 'auto',  // Allows width to adjust dynamically
        },
      }}
    />
  );
}

export default DynamicWidthTextField;
```

I also added `sx={{display:"flex",flexGrow:0}}` and even `inputProps={{style:{display:"flex",flexGrow:0}}}` on the TextField component but they had no effects.